# Compiling two projects together in Code Blocks

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and tutorial asks me to add another project to what I have now.
Also I'm asked to use forward declaration so I can make use of that added file.

Here is my main project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "io.cpp"
using namespace std;


int readNumber();

void writeResult(int x);


int main() {

    int x = readNumber();
    int y = readNumber();
    writeResult(x + y);
    return 0;


}
```

here's the added file called io.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int readNumber() {


    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void writeResult(int x) {
    cout << "Sum of your numbers is " << x << endl;
}
```

[![And here's a screenshot so you can see what error I'm getting which talks about multiple definition and you can see where those two files are added.
According to the tutorial my code is okay but compiler complains. Why ?][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT89X.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT89X.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code Blocks, but you must compile the two source files individually, and then link the resulting object files together to make on executable.

Answer (score 0):

In codeblocks, when creating a new class, it should automatically header file. Programming with header files is the best practice out there. Here's the code I tried and it worked, with io.h.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "io.h"

using namespace std;

io inOut;


int main()
{

    int x = inOut.readNumber();
    int y = inOut.readNumber();
    inOut.writeResult(x + y);
    return 0;

}
```

**io.h**

```
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H


class io
{
    public:
        int readNumber();
        void writeResult(int);
};

#endif
```

**io.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "io.h"

using namespace std;

int io::readNumber()
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void io::writeResult(int x)
{
    cout << "Sum of your numbers is " << x << endl;
}
```

I used codeblocks to compile the code written above, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Strange coz I'm not instructed to do it this way. I'm taking the course from the beginning ... there might be something I missed. Instructions says to have only main.cpp and io.cpp. I'll be learning nuts and bolts about headers in next lessons. Thanks for taking time !

Answer (score 0):

Well as turns out when adding more cpps they're not supposed to be #included on the top. That's what makes compiler say that function is being defined multiple times. All I had to do was just get rid off that one line.

Here's my source:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/44651/